# Rich Text Dialogs for Touch UI in AEM 6.5

Tags: aem, richtext

I want to create Rich Text dialog in AEM 6.5

I have added the RTE plugins and UI settings but still it is not working.

[image]

Please see the attached image of the structure of rich text dialog.

Do we need to write some code or class so that rich text dialogs can work.
Please help.

Comment: Please share your dialog xml file to get the better Idea of properties.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to figure out if you have done anything wrong is to copy the richtext from `/libs/core/wcm/components/text/v1/text/cq:dialog/content/items/tabs/items/properties/items/columns/items/column/items/text` to your dialog and check if the RTE is appearing or not. If it is, then compare the one you previously created with this one and figure out what is going wrong.

Always the best approach is to check the OOTB fields structure and compare it with your structure to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[Rich Text Editor in Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPfu2.png)

It is always better to configure dialogs directly with XML instead of doing it in CRXDE.
To start with you can look into the '[Text Component](https://www.aemcomponents.dev/content/core-components-examples/library/core-content/text.html)' dialog which has RTE in its dialog.

Look into the `<text>...</text>` part in the [content.xml](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/main/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/text/v1/text/_cq_dialog/.content.xml) of the dialog. Hopefully, you will get a better idea.